# Free PHP link exchange script

Tags: gratis, open-source, php

Currently I'm using a script called [linkex](http://linkex.dk/). It seems that the website is down as of now and I have been getting quite a few errors like the following:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method linkex::get() should not be called
>   statically in /usr/home/alexus/thespacesurf.com/linkex/index.php on
>   line 13,15,17,53,54,1440,3775

This shows that the script is *no longer maintained* and therefore requires that I find a new script.

I'm looking for a PHP Link Exchange Script that meets these requirements,

- A script that runs on PHP version 5.6.13
- Gratis (free/open source)
- Is being updated and maintained frequently
- Has reCAPTCHA support

Comment: Could you expand on what your looking for? There are quite a few link exchange scripts that are free - adding some requirements could help narrow down the results, thanks.

Comment: Google found quite a few, challenge is to pick one out of so many, I figured http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be a good fit here for this question and in terms of requirements; a popular open source project with few maintaners.

Comment: I understand, I'm just asking for more specifics otherwise it makes this question way to broad and would be subject to closure. Could you add some specifics on like what PHP version your running, what features you want in the application, etc.? This again helps narrow down the recommendations to find the best one that would suit your needs. ok, I see you edited your comment, could you add this to your question? Thanks again